# How to serve(GET) Complex(Nested) JSON from C# Web API Visual Studio 2017 RTM that has a Many-to-Many relationship?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, get, ef-code-first

I've been stuck on this problem for a long time now.

My environment:

- Visual Studio 2017 RTM (Using the default .net core version of this IDE)
- Web API
- ASP.NET core 1.1
- MySQL via Pomelo database provider

The packages I installed:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

I have 3 tables created using code first.

- Employee: Has list of employees
- Application: List of Applications
- EmployeeApplications: The Join table for Employees and Applications

Employee and Application have a M:M relationship so I created the join table between them.

Employee Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Test.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FName { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        //Navigation Property
        public ICollection<EmployeeApplications> EmployeeApplications { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Application Model:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Teset.Models
{
    public class Application
    {
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        //Navigation Property
        public ICollection<EmployeeApplications> EmployeeApplications { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EmployeeApplications Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test.Models
{
    public class EmployeeApplications
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public Application Application { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Employee Controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Employees")]
public class EmployeesController : Controller
{
    private readonly TestContext _context;

    public EmployeesController(TestContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Employees
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return _context.Employees;
    }
```

Context:

```
using Test.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Test.Data
{
    public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmployeeApplications> EmployeeApplications { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeApplications>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.EmployeeId, c.ApplicationId });
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using .Include(). When I run and go to api/Employees I get "Could not get any response" from Postman.

```
return _context.Employees.Include(e => e.EmployeeApplications);
```

I have tried many variations on this, still no luck. Any variation that included `.Include()` fails.

Sample of current output:

```
[{
    "employeeId": 1,
    "lName": "Doe",
    "fName": "John",
    "title": "Senior Software Engineer",
    "employeeApplications": null
},
{
    "employeeId": 2,
    "lName": "Smith",
    "fName": "Jack",
    "title": "Project Manager",
    "employeeApplications": null
}]
```

I tried using a DTO and that had some success. I managed to replace the nulls above with content from employeeApplications, but then that had null references to Employee and Applications.

My ideal output:

```
[{
    "employeeId": 1,
    "lName": "Doe",
    "fName": "John",
    "title": "Senior Software Engineer",
    "employeeApplications": [{
        "applicationId": 1,
        "name": "Application 1",
        "description": "Description 1",
    },
    {
        "applicationId": 2,
        "name": "Application 2",
        "description": "Description 2",
    }]
},
{
    "employeeId": 2,
    "lName": "Smith",
    "fName": "Jack",
    "title": "Project Manager",
    "employeeApplications": [{
        "applicationId": 2,
        "name": "Application 2",
        "description": "Description 2",
    },
    {
        "applicationId": 3,
        "name": "Application 3",
        "description": "Description 3",
    }]
}]
```

Basically I want to serve a list of "Employees" and the Applications they work on. Later I will also want to serve a list of Applications and the Employees that work on them.

**EDIT**: Added context file above

**Edit 2**: I followed Bchir Med Amine's solution (not currently working), but then I added to the `ConfigureServices` method of Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(
                    options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                );
```

This gets me more information on my JSON, still not complete. JSON now looks like this:

```
[{
    "employeeId": 1,
    "lName": "Doe",
    "fName": "John",
    "title": "Senior Software Engineer",
    "employeeApplications": [{
        "employeeId": 1,
        "applicationId": 1,
        "application": null
    },
    {
        "employeeId": 1,
        "applicationId": 2,
        "application": null
    }]
},
{
    "employeeId": 2,
    "lName": "Smith",
    "fName": "Jack",
    "title": "Project Manager",
    "employeeApplications": [{
        "employeeId": 2,
        "applicationId": 2,
        "application": null
    },
    {
        "employeeId": 2,
        "applicationId": 3,
        "application": null
    }]
}]
```

Application is now null. I had to use .Include() to generate this, but using .ThenInclude() after to include applications did not work. Again the ideal situation would be to print out a list of all employees, each employee should have a list of applications.

**Edit 3**: I was wrong about `.ThenInclude()` not working, it was Intelisense that was throwing me off. If I use .ThenInclud() I get this JSON:

```
[{
    "employeeId": 1,
    "lName": "Doe",
    "fName": "John",
    "title": "Senior Software Engineer",
    "employeeApplications": [{
        "employeeId": 1,
        "applicationId": 1,
        "application": {
            "applicationId": 1,
            "name": "Application 1",
            "description": "Description 1",
            "employeeApplications": []
        }
    },
    {
        "employeeId": 1,
        "applicationId": 2,
        "application": {
            "applicationId": 2,
            "name": "Application 2",
            "description": "Description 2",
            "employeeApplications": []
        }
    }]
},
{
    "employeeId": 2,
    "lName": "Smith",
    "fName": "Jack",
    "title": "Project Manager",
    "employeeApplications": [{
        "employeeId": 2,
        "applicationId": 2,
        "application": {
            "applicationId": 2,
            "name": "Application 2",
            "description": "Description 2",
            "employeeApplications": [{
                "employeeId": 1,
                "applicationId": 2,
                "employee": {
                    "employeeId": 1,
                    "lName": "Doe",
                    "fName": "John",
                    "title": "Senior Software Engineer",
                    "employeeApplications": [{
                        "employeeId": 1,
                        "applicationId": 1,
                        "application": {
                            "applicationId": 1,
                            "name": "Application 1",
                            "description": "Description 1",
                            "employeeApplications": []
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        "employeeId": 2,
        "applicationId": 3,
        "application": {
            "applicationId": 3,
            "name": "Application 3",
            "description": "Description 3",
            "employeeApplications": []
        }
    }]
}]
```

The first employee object is Ok(still not ideal, but it can work), but the second employee is not. The second prints out the applications of employees, and then also prints out the employees of those applications.

**Edit 4**: Here are the ways in which I am returning the JSON:

```
return _context.Employees; //Returns just employees and '[]' for employeeApplications
return _context.Employees.Include(e => e.EmployeeApplications); //returns employees and their employeeApplications, but the applications of employeeApplications is empty
return _context.Employees.Include(e => e.EmployeeApplications).ThenInclude(ea => ea.Application); //returns everything, but continues due to circular reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of trying to use `.Include()` I went back to DTOs.

I arrived at a solution, but I don't know if it could be used later when I need to alter the Application get() method.

My solution starts from my original code before Bchir Med Amine's suggestions(It works with his code too, but I went back for simplicity).

First Create a `DTO.cs` file in your models folder. in it put these classes:

```
public class EmployeeDTO
{

    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }


    //Navigation Property
    public List<EmployeeApplicationsDTO> EmployeeApplicationsDTO { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeApplicationsDTO
{
    public Application Application { get; set; }

}
```

Next in the EmployeesController's `GetEmployees()` method use this code:

```
return _context.Employees.Select(e => new EmployeeDTO
{
    LName = e.LName,
    FName = e.FName,
    Title = e.Title,
    EmployeeApplicationsDTO = e.EmployeeApplications.Select(ea => new EmployeeApplicationsDTO
    {
        Application = ea.Application
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

That's it. Here's the JSON:

```
[{
    "lName": "Doe",
    "fName": "John",
    "title": "Senior Software Engineer",
    "employeeApplicationsDTO": [{
        "application": {
            "applicationId": 1,
            "name": "Application 1",
            "description": "Description 1",
            "employeeApplications": null
        }
    },
    {
        "application": {
            "applicationId": 2,
            "name": "Application 2",
            "description": "Description 2",
            "employeeApplications": null
        }
    }]
},
{
    "lName": "Smith",
    "fName": "Jack",
    "title": "Project Manager",
    "employeeApplicationsDTO": [{
        "application": {
            "applicationId": 2,
            "name": "Application 2",
            "description": "Description 2",
            "employeeApplications": null
        }
    },
    {
        "application": {
            "applicationId": 3,
            "name": "Application 3",
            "description": "Description 3",
            "employeeApplications": null
        }
    }]
}]
```

As you can see it is not perfect, but it will allow me to continue developing the rest of the app.

The DTO allows me to show only the data I want to show. But something is still off about my object structure.  To get applications that an engineer works on I have to drill into it:

`Employee[x].employeeApplicationDTO[y].application.name`

The `.application.` doesn't seem necessary, but I can't solve that now.

I post this as an answer because it's the progress I have made, if someone else comes up with a better solution I will try it and give them credit.

Comment: Getting an error on the `{get; set;}` of `Application application` `'MediaTypenames.Application' static types cannot be used as return types` Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have to add Virtual to classes

```
public class Application
{
    #region Public Constructors

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Application()
    {
        EmployeeApplications = new HashSet<EmployeeApplications>();
    }

    #endregion Public Constructors

    #region Public Properties

    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    //Navigation Property
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeApplications> EmployeeApplications { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    #endregion Public Properties
}

public class Employee
{
    #region Public Constructors

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Employee()
    {
        EmployeeApplications = new HashSet<EmployeeApplications>();
    }

    #endregion Public Constructors

    #region Public Properties

    //Navigation Property
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeApplications> EmployeeApplications { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LName { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    #endregion Public Properties
}

public class EmployeeApplications
{
    #region Public Properties

    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    #endregion Public Properties
}
```

Comment: I tested a few combinations based on this answer. 1.Adding virtual to the 2 models you listed. 2. Adding virtual to all 3 models I mentioned. 3. without .Include() in the controller/ with .Include()/ with .include().ToList(). 
No combination worked.
But if I used virtual and no .Include() I get JSON just like before(with nulls)

Comment: Virtual properties are there to allow lazy loading , and dont forget to put the EmployeeApplications on the context

Comment: I added my context to my question. Note that I had added more in the `OnModelCreating` method before as a potential fix, but that didn't do anything.  I'm not sure I understand your solution. I added virtual to my models and I am still getting nulls. Also, in your answer, you list the same class `Applications` twice. I'm brand new to this so you have to be explicit when telling me things to do. As for Lazy Loading, I thought I would want Eager because I want the child objects loaded with parent(Load Applications of Employees along with Employees)

Comment: my bad , i though i copied Employee .

Comment: i added the ctor try it now

Comment: There is a change in the output. Now instead of `employeeApplications` being `null` in the JSON, it is now an empt array `[]`.  But I am still not getting the applications printed.  Maybe the issue is now in the controller? Maybe I need some logic there to output the Applications of the Employees?

Comment: By adding `services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(
                    options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                );` to Startup.cs configureServices method I get the next layer in the JSON.  This layer is the array of employeeApplications. But employee applications has null for applications.  Ideally EmployeeApplications would not even show up.

Comment: ok i want u to put the _context.Employees.Include(e => e.EmployeeApplications) in variable and test it with debug to see if the problem is from encoding to json or the data isn't loading

Comment: I put it in a variable and returned that variable, then ran it in debug. The output is the same as if it were not in variable.  That is to say, It prints employees and their employeeApplications, but the employeeApplications do not print out the Applications. I added my return calls to my post under edit 4 and a description of their outputs.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this as models

```
 public class Application
    {
        #region Public Constructors

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Application()
        {
            Employee = new HashSet<Employee>();
        }

        #endregion Public Constructors

        #region Public Properties

        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        //Navigation Property
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        #endregion Public Properties
    }
```

---

```
    public class Employee
    {
        #region Public Constructors

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Employee()
        {
            Applications = new HashSet<Application>();
        }

        #endregion Public Constructors

        #region Public Properties

        //Navigation Property
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

        public virtual ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LName { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        #endregion Public Properties
    }
```

Comment: in the constructors of both of the classes I get an error on the Left Hand of the assignment. I tried both plural and singular forms of Engineer/Application(since you mixed them). But neither works. When singular, the error is: "'X' is a type but is used like a variable".  When plural, error is: "The name 'X' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: add this to onModelCreating

`modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Application)
                .WithMany(e => e.Employee)
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("Employee_Application").MapLeftKey("EmployeeID").MapRightKey("ApplicationId "));`

Comment: I changed `e.Application` to `e.Applications` because it was an error otherwise("'Employee' does not contain a definition for 'Application' ..."), but then the `WithMany()` became an error: "'CollectionNavigationBuilder,Employee, Application>' does not contain a definition for 'WithMany' and no extension method 'WithMany' accepting a first argument of type 'CollectionNavigationBuilder<Employee, Application>' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: i'm giving up sorry , try to manipulate the result of return `_context.Employees.Include(e => e.EmployeeApplications).ThenInclude(ea => ea.Application);` using an intermediaire class and form the result using linq before sending it back